# Is it possible to use RealityKit with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, arkit, realitykit

As the title says, is it possible to use RealityKit with objective-c?  I've tried using both ARView and creating a simple swift wrapper for ARView.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TestARView-Bridging-Header.h"
#import "TestARView-Swift.h"

@class ARTestView;
@class ARView;

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    ARTestView* a = [[ARTestView alloc] init];
    ARView* a = [[ARView alloc] init];
}
```

When I compile I get an error originating from the "RealityKit-Swift.h" file:

Module 'UIKitCore' not found.

I have included the "RealityKit.framework" info my application.

I've never had trouble using swift in my objective-c applications before.  Perhaps Apple had dropped support for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that RealityKit cannot be used in an objective-c application.  This is because UIKitCore is a swift only framework and is not supported in objective-c and has NOT been released yet.  RealityKit-Swift.h includes the following imports:

```
@import ARKit;
@import CoreGraphics;
@import ObjectiveC;
@import UIKitCore;
```

UIKitCore is NOT a library supported by Apple.  As a result, RealityKit CANNOT be used by an objective-c application.  I have filed a bug report with Apple.  However, I am not holding my breath as Objective-C is no longer supported by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

RealityKit can be used in the Swift files only.

So just implement all RealityKit in swift file. And then include it to you solution.
You can freely use swift classes in Obj-C. Import "**-Swift.h**" and not forget to mark your swift classes with **@obj** directive.